# Visual Studio 2019 taking up loads of CPU and serving a simple asp.net **very** slowly

Tags: asp.net, performance, asp.net-web-api, cpu, visual-studio-2019

So I've started to get into the whole .NET Web Development. Following a simple tutorial I have set up a simple web API project.

As I have created the project based on a template, there was a default ASP.NET MVC Website included it this projects which contains the default homepage and the api documentation.

When I was exploring this API documentation I noticed that loading just one page takes an incredibly long time. I was wondering if there is anything i am doing wrong.

This is the only part of the application I have really touched (creating a controller and adding some values to the api responses)

```
public class PeopleController : ApiController
{
    List<Person> people = new List<Person>()

    public PeopleController()
    {
        people.Add(new Person { Id = 1, FirstName = "Bla", LastName = "Foo" });
        people.Add(new Person { Id = 2, FirstName = "Bla1", LastName = "Foo1" });
        people.Add(new Person { Id = 3, FirstName = "Bla2", LastName = "Foo2" }); 
    }

    [Route("api/People/GetFirstNames")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> GetFirstNames()
    {
        return people.Select(person => person.FirstName); 
    }

    public List<Person> Get()
    {
        return people;
    }

    public Person Get(int id)
    {
        return people.Where(person => person.Id == id).FirstOrDefault(); 
    }

    public void Post(Person person)
    {
        people.Add(person); 
    }

    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }
}
```

Now opening a page in the API section takes about 2 minutes (without debugging), which i think is insane, especially since i running apis (and websites) on .NET would be a good thing for performance and speed.

[Screenshot of the response time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLNqP.png)

Also Visual Studio eats up about 90% of my CPU which might be the root cause of this problem (i have not tried to deploy the app yet)

[Visual Studio Web Api CPU consumption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlRQV.png)

So does anyone know what on earth is visual studio 2019 doing to take up so much CPU? (I am using an AMD FX(tm)-8350 Eight-Core Processor 4.00 GHz, which i think should be enough to handle Visual Studio).

Besides the language settings, i have not changed anything about the default settings after installing Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition. Anyone can help?

Comment: Visual Studio does use a lot of resources. I usually see mine using over a gig of memory. How much ram do you have? I am surprised how slow it is for you. You could try disabling IntelliSense.

Comment: I have 16 gb of memory. I would like to use IntelliSense while programming in VS, any other ideas?

Comment: Make sure you run your app only. This includes turning off any additions like App Insights. Also, is only the first request that is slow or every other request to the already running app is also that slow?

Comment: I will try that thank you. Could you point me to a resource which lists all the things running besides the app? 
Every request to a new page takes that long, and the more request I make, the more CPU visual studio takes up.

Answer (score 0):

I have reinstalled Visual Studio 2019 and removed all packages that were not necessary for web development.

It seems like this solved the problem i had.